# Cant fetch json and viewing it in angular unless i edit the json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to access a json with the exact same format:

```
 {"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
 ]}
```

script:

```
    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('employees/employees.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.resources = data;
       });
```

if i remove the "employees" so its only the attributes inside the [] iwill get my data. but if left like the example above i cant reach my data.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$scope.resources = data.employees;`

Comment: omg thank u. Im learning angular an JS and the whole bunch so alot to keep a hold of :P

Can I ask you. I have a json that contains links to other json objects. How would i approach to be able to click the link and view the newly clicked json link?

Comment: depends...you may need to show some more code of how your page is setup, the HTML etc. But that may be a whole new question.

Comment: so far it not much code just an ng-repeater with a filter to be able to filter out.Its supposed to end up as an browser where one can browse trough an web api where everything is json. Ill see what i can do before i consult stack again.
thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just follow the structure of the JSON. Since data is the entire JSON string then the array of employees is accessible via the employees key. Try this:

```
   $scope.resources = data.employees;
```

Comment: yes ur example worked from a local json. Thank!

But i want to acces it from an url can i still use the same approach as above? or must i use jquery/ajax?

Comment: Should work same if the JSON returned from the URL is the same.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to mention that u need authentication to access the url.json. So to access the api i need to authenticate. 

`** var base = "/api/resources/";; Ext.onReady( function() { Ext.Ajax.request({ url: base + "/login.action", method: "POST", params: { j_username: "admin", j_password: "admin" }, success: setLinks }); }); **`


this is the provided code from the api on how to authenticate. Im not sure how to implement this into my existing code so i can acces the json exernally and not only locally.